# Mongoose find max value of a field with hexadecimal value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a field `code` that contains a value in hexadecimal.

How can I get the highest value in the collection in one mongoose query?

If I have several collection with the same field `code`, is there a way to get the highest value based on all the collections in one request?

Comment: "value in hexadecimal". That's a string, right?

Comment: Yes, it is a string.

Comment: probably the best choice would be to add a number field representing that value.

Comment: So, I assume it is not possible to do so, like converting the hexa into integer then extract the highest value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally to find maximum value of a field you need to either:

1. Have an index on that field - then the retrieval is relatively quick - you just take the first item in inverse sort. The problem here is that if you index hexadecimal strings, the order will be lexicographical, so the maximum will be the lexicographical maximum of the string set.

   That's why adding an integer field would be the best choice if this operation is going to be repeated many times.

   Besides, it's probably better from the pure data-modelling point of view. The field is actually an integer, the hex string is just it's representation, so maybe it should be converted to hex only when presented to the end user?
2. Iterate all the elements of the collection while maintaining and updating max value. This can be easily done using a simple `.forEach` on the mongo cursor:

   ```
   var max = some_small_value;
   cur.forEach(function (doc) {
       var current = parseInt(doc.field, 16);
       if (max < current) {
            max = current;
       }   
   });
   ```

   Or in mongoose, using query streams:

   ```
    var stream = Model.find().stream();
    var max = some_small_value;

    stream.on('data', function (doc) {
       var current = parseInt(doc.field, 16);
       if (max < current) {
            max = current;
       }   
    });
    stream.on('close', function () {
       // do something with max
    })
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I think the best solution in my case is to take the latest row and take its `code`, the lastest would always have the highest value in the collection. It would be a good workaround here I guess, assuming the highest value is always the most recent.

Comment: @Vadorequest yes, if you can assume that then the problem is easier - what you need is that value from the last document.

Comment: I mean it's still the same problem - finding a document with the max value, but at least that value is a date and easily indexable.